# application/x-httpd-php save file option while trying to access website

Tags: php, web-hosting

I am using Unlimited web hosting server. I uploaded my website written in PHP code.

While I enter site url to browser, it does not open rather provides downloading option.

Please provide me a best solution for this.

If my question is unclear, please comment. :)

Comment: Sounds like your hoster doesn't support PHP. You really should ask their support.

Comment: I have three websites hosting in same server. Only one is not working. So, I don't think hosting server does not support PHP.

Comment: Based on your description the only answer possible is: "You did something wrong."

Comment: Please post the code of index file...

Comment: Something is wrong for sure. I uploaded simple html file home.html and try to access in url http://example.com/home.html 
It gives 404 error (page not found).

Let me describe what I have done. I have a website http://example.com (lets say) hosted in Unlimited web hosting sever with unlimited space. 
Second, registered a domain lets say http://example1.com. Now I changed NS of example1.com same as example.com and copied all files to its server and try to access the example1.com.

This is not working. What am I suppose to do now?